# Puma server won't start, libssl error - cannot find file

Tags: puma, libssl

I'm getting the following error when trying to start puma. It is complaining that it cannot load libssl?

Any ideas?

```
root@7711398a00ad:/app# bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/bundle/bin/puma)
LoadError: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/puma_http11.so
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:15:in `require'
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/runner.rb:1:in `require'
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/runner.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/cluster.rb:1:in `require'
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/cluster.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/launcher.rb:4:in `require'
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/launcher.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/cli.rb:6:in `require'
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/cli.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/bin/puma:6:in `require'
  /bundle/gems/puma-3.11.4/bin/puma:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /bundle/bin/puma:23:in `load'
  /bundle/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 6):

libssl1.0.0 was pulled for security reasons. Upgrading the puma gem to the latest version (3.11.4 -> 3.12.0) fixed it for me.